# ¿Eliminar lineas sin patrón con sed?

Tags: linux, csv, sed

¿Existe algún **comando de sed** para **eliminar** todas **las líneas de un archivo** CSV que **no correspondan con un determinado patrón**?

Tengo un archivo CSV enorme, y me interesa ver solamente las líneas cuya última columna corresponde con un patrón de caracteres. Gracias.

Comment: No. Hay un comando para buscar y hay otro para borrar líneas, pero no hay uno que haga ambas cosas: consulta [el manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.txt).

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta con un ejemplo del archivo y del patrón que buscas.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba de la siguiente manera:

```
sed '/patrón/!d' archivo
```

También:

```
sed -n '/patrón/p' archivo
```

Cualquiera de los dos te dará sólo las líneas que contienen el patrón.